# I cannot use apt-get : libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, libstdc++

I have an issue with apt, when I'm using apt-get update for example I get this error :

```
 apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: no command with apt-get works!

Comment: You completely broke your OS, what exactly did you do? Simply reinstall ubuntu to fix this.